# Open source Desktop Application architecture/framework?

Tags: architecture, desktop-application

I am looking for something like Ruby on Rails, which is open source, has an architecture (MVC or whatever) but is used for Desktop Applications.

Can you suggest anything?

Thanks.

Comment: What desktop environment are you targeting? Windows, Linux, Apple, or a combination?

Comment: @AdrianK, I am working on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution.
The [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) library is a good choice when using WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any desktop / thick-client frameworks - at least none like rails, etc.

If you're target platform is Windows then you'll be looking for .Net based platforms.  Depending on what you're doing there might also be Office libraries that can "help", but be careful of dependencies and forward planning.

The MS Enterprise Libraries have various libraries that will help application development in general, and there is at least on library devoted to UI / presentation aspects but I've never used it.  Although they won't really give you the application structure / framework in the way that rails does, they will help in other areas.

I also recommend looking at www.codeplex.com, as that is the best windows / .net Open Source website I know of.